# How to run a background task infinitely

Tags: python, flask, redis

I have a need for a background task that runs infinitely and writes to the database every 30 minutes.

I'm using Flask with redis and rq.

Right now I have redis-server running, I have a worker listening to the queue and when running the flask application I provide that worker with the function that needs to run.

I want the action to happen every time the clock is at 30 minutes or 0 minutes:

server startup code:

```
app.redis = Redis.from_url(app.config['REDIS_URL'])
app.task_queue = rq.Queue('tasks', connection=app.redis)
app.task_queue.enqueue('app.tasks.my_infinite_task')
```

task code:

```
current_minutes = None
    while True:
        minutes = datetime.utcnow().minute
        if minutes == 0 or minutes == 30:
            if current_minutes is None or minutes != current_minutes:
                current_minutes = minutes
                for user in User.query.all():
                    user.count += 1
                db.session.commit()
        sleep(1)
```

Is this the right approach?
Right now it's working but not consistent, after a long time I'm getting a `JobTimeoutException` (could be unrelated?)

My end goal would be that every time the server restarts, the queues would get emptied and workers would be restarted (if possible) and this task would run infintely in the background.

Comment: Sounds like the right task for a cron job.

Comment: I'll look into it, thank you